# How do you say “Because I do not speak fluent German, I have drawn diagrams which are on my blog.”?

Tags: translation

I’m struggling to say

“Because I do not speak fluent German, I have drawn diagrams, which are on my blog.

Comment: Well done. Slight improvement lies in usage of the 'Modalverb' können at the end: "damit du sehen kannst/ Sie sehen können, ...". Also, there is usually a space inserted after a forward slash.

Comment: "Also, there is usually a space inserted after a forward slash" Citation needed. The way OP uses the slash is fine, the way you're using it looks... strange.

Comment: I think there is quite a bit of ambiguity in both, 'diagramme' as well as 'measurements'. Can you please detail what kind of diagrammes and what kind of measurements you mean? Is it about lengths for clothes? Is it about permissible pressures and pipe diameters for a gas turbine? Is it Is it about points in an acre where soil humidity is being measured? Depending on context and the actual activity needed, different words for these words seem appropriate

Comment: I think there is no need to reference that you are not fluent in German. A simple, "please take a look at these sketches and tell report the measurements to me" would suffice.

Answer (score 2):

There are no severe problems with this, it's **valid German**.

However, in case you are interested and want to have some perspective from a native speaker I may share some things I would change. As there is no context I have to guess a little bit what exactly you are talking about.

The start 'Da ich Deutsch nicht fließend spreche' makes it **harder to read**, because you are referencing 'nicht fließend' to something which came earlier in the sentence. The **eye might jump back to re-read** 'Deutsch'. Rearranging fixes this: 'Da ich nicht fließend Deutsch spreche, ...'.

Next up the phrase 'Diagramme gezeichnet' is a little bit strange. The situation seems like you want something customized, e.g. a shirt or a dress. 'Diagramm' in German could be some pie or stock chart. But you are probably relating to a so-called '**Skizze**', which is a sketch with some basic lines forming what you want customized and the measurements as numbers on it.

So you could go ahead and write 'Skizze gezeichnet', but then I'd argue 'gezeichnet' is something you spent a lot of time on creating and which is very accurately drawn. The word '**angefertigt**' seems a better fit, because that's similar to 'made' in English **without any nuance attached** to it.

Now it might get a little bit controversial. Your **sentences are rather long** and you may finish the first sentence after this amount of information. The next important piece of information is the blog. '**You may find the diagrams at xy**' sounds **more encouraging** to get a person to look at them than 'the diagrams are at xy'.

The last 'I have done this so you can see exactly which measurements I need' **seems redundant** after that, because you just shared a diagram which has those precise measurements. A person would (hopefully) not read 143cm and say 'Hey, let's make this 150cm'

This results in:

**Da ich nicht fließend Deutsch spreche, habe ich Skizzen meiner Maße angefertigt. Sie finden die Skizzen auf meinem Blog: URL**